# Sort grid with json content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

i am using w2ui [w2ui.com](http://w2ui.com) for displaying a grid.
when the grid records are stored local inside the html file sorting is working.

but i want to use this function dynamically on a json-file.

i have this json file (test.json):

```
{
    total: 9,
    page: 0,
    records: [
        { recid: 11, fname: 'John', lname: 'Doe', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 12, fname: 'Stuart', lname: 'Motzart', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 13, fname: 'Jin', lname: 'Franson', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 14, fname: 'Susan', lname: 'Ottie', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 15, fname: 'Kelly', lname: 'Silver', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 16, fname: 'Francis', lname: 'Gatos', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 17, fname: 'Mark', lname: 'Welldo', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 18, fname: 'Thomas', lname: 'Bahh', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 19, fname: 'Sergei', lname: 'Rachmaninov', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' }
    ]
}
```

i get it load in a grid, with this code:

```
$('#grid-customers').w2grid({ 
    name: 'grid-customers',
    url: 'data/test.json',

    columns: [              
        { field: 'recid', caption: 'ID', size: '50px', sortable: true, attr: 'align=center' },
        { field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name', size: '30%', sortable: true },
        { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', size: '30%', sortable: true },
        { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', size: '40%' },
        { field: 'sdate', caption: 'Start Date', size: '120px' },
    ]

});
```

but i can not sort it or search for content inside the grid.
everytime when i click on the grid header (for column sorting) i see the sorting arrow and a pop-up called "refreshing..." but the columns do not get sorted.

Answer (score 1):

From the site:

> If data is local, the grid will perform local sorting. If data is
>   remote, the grid will submit sort fields to the server side.

What this means is if you load the data from an outside source (even a static file) *using the url property* the plugin is going to try to send sorting commands to the remote source and expect it to do the work.

The two options you have are:

1. Move the data into the page you are working on to permit local sorting
2. Use a server backed page that can receive sorting commands and return the data formatted in a way that the plugin expects

Comment: I'd think you could also use a separate custom $.json() function that gets the content and then present it to this w2grid as "local" data? No?

Comment: @Eric Tung is there a tutorial out there to handle JSON sorting on server side over POST-methode?

Comment: @funkwurm could be a solution but i want to use the save/delete button and function from the w2grid